# Getting container to be full viewport width and height, static (with inner scroll on div)

Tags: html, css

I'm not concerned about mobile, but my issue here is on laptop screens, monitors, etc. using bootstrap (though I'm open to using flex if it will be better overall)

This will hold a map in the large column and a list of locations in the small column, but the key I'm trying to achieve right now is a static container that is 100% width and height of the viewport (minus 60px for the header) and no scrolling outside of it. The idea is that the list of locations is an inner/hidden scroll (if that makes sense).

How can I get this container overall to sit full width and height without the ability to scroll outside of it? Even if there are 150 listings, I don't want it to push the height of the stores-list div, I want it to be only an inner scroll

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<header style="height:60px;">
<ul style="display:flex;">
<li>Home</li>
<li>About</li>
</ul>
</header>
<div  style="width:100%; margin:0 auto; height: calc(100% - 60px)!important ; max-width:100% !important;">
  <div class="row" style="height: calc(100% - 60px); !important;">
    <div class="col-lg-8" id="maplist-area" >
      <div id="map" style="margin-top:20px; width:100%; height:100%;border:1px solid red;">
      </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="col-lg-4">
       <div style="padding-top:35px; margin-bottom:20px;">
          <form id="mapSR" class="home-form" method="post">
          <input id="ss" type="text" name="locationSearch" placeholder="search" style="border-radius:18px; padding:4px; width: 100%;" />
          </form>
       </div>
       <div id="stores-list" class="stores-list" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 80%;">    
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this can be fixed by using `height: calc(100vh - 60px);` instead of `height: calc(100% - 60px);`

Comment: @JonasGrumann That does help with the fit, but it still allows scrolling outside of the whole container as well as the stores-list expanding past the viewport (making the whole container taller than the viewport

Comment: For the container being taller you'll have to play with the calc values. As for the scrolling I don't understand what you mean. You want to completely disable the scrolling on the page? `html, body {overflow: hidden;}`

Comment: Yes just on this page I want this container to be full width/height and static so that you can't make the page scroll around it. The stores-list div is the only thing that should scroll but it should be an inner scroll (which it technically is, if I make the height static like 500px;)

Comment: I see, I made an example with fresh code but it should be easily adaptable to yours: https://jsfiddle.net/ocmuf563/